# Java library for rendering

Tags: java, rendering

We have some shapefile data and we tried to render them according to scope (boundingbox) from user.

For example, the client may send request like this:

```
layer=river&width=256&height=256&bbox=....
```

Then I will generate an image accordingly.

I know this is similar to a WMS server, however I do not want to use GeoSever or something else. They are heavy. I just have two shapefiles  with a fixed style.

And I found that GeoSever use GeoTools as the render library, so I tried to use GeoTools myself, however I found that GeoTools does not provide an acceptable performance.

So I wonder if there are any alternative solutions?

Comment: Could you re-read and then edit your question to try and make it clearer, please?  For example, your first sentence leaves me guessing where/how you may have "tried to render them according to bbox from user".

Comment: By saying that Geotools is not fast enough, have you verified for example with Geoserver or uDig that it is just geotools which is slow or could your code perhaps be sub-optimal? Rendering from shapefiles with BBOX limits should be pretty fast if spatial index exists and it is utilised. About other alternatives, OpenJUMP is java and lightweight and it renders shapefiles but I do not know how easy it would be to rip just the rendering part out of it.